# CGI script with .py or .cgi extension

Tags: python, cgi

Which one is preferred or the "right practice" for running a CGI script on a web host from the cgi-bin directory? Both written in Python. Thanks.

**hello.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print '<html>'
print '<head>'
print '<title>Hello Word - First CGI Program</title>'
print '</head>'
print '<body>'
print '<h2>Hello Word! This is my first CGI program</h2>'
print '</body>'
print '</html>'
```

**hello.cgi**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print '<html>'
print '<head>'
print '<title>Hello Word - First CGI Program</title>'
print '</head>'
print '<body>'
print '<h2>Hello Word! This is my first CGI program</h2>'
print '</body>'
print '</html>'
```

Comment: Neither. Running CGI scripts at all is not considered best practice.

Comment: I am writing a very basic script with no framework for an email contact form; wouldn't this suffice? Bare-bones.